# Automatic logout inactivity/idle after 2 or 3 minutes my application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How to set up in the rails application that if user is idle or inactive for 30 minutes he should be automatically get logged out. I am using devise for authentication purpose.

I have setup like this but doesn't work.

`config/initializers/session_store.rb`

**Rails.application.config.session_store ActionDispatch::Session::CacheStore, :expire_after => 30.minutes, key: Settings.server.session_key, domain: ".#{Settings.server.domain}"**

Can any one give any solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add :timeoutable in your User.rb or whatever model you are using for devise

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable
```

and then in your devise.rb Just uncomment this line.

```
> # ==> Configuration for :timeoutable
> # The time you want to timeout the user session without activity. After this
> # time the user will be asked for credentials again. Default is 30 minutes.


config.timeout_in = 30.minutes
```

Set whatever time you want to.